# DRY: a case with AsyncTasks

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, dry

I'm developing an Android app which has a lot of different requests for web services.
Every request is done in a subclass of `AsyncTask` in this manner:

```
(new AsyncTask<String, Void, Object1>() {
    @Override
    protected Object1 doInBackground(String... params) {
        // network request and parsing to Object1
        Object1 obj = new Object1();
        obj1 = Parser.parseObject1(httpClient.execute(...));
        return obj1;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object1 onPostExecute(Object1... ret) {
        return ret[0];
    }
}).execute();
```

`Object1` is a placeholder for different objects (`Car`, `Bicycle`, `Truck`...), each one in a different `AsyncTask`.

What are my alternatives other than returning the output of httpClient in a `String` and parsing in the Main Thread (UI Thread)? Avoid parsing in the UI Thread sounds reasonable if it's going to parse a lot of data, am I right?

**-= UPDATE =-**

Let me rephrase the question: I'm asking for a more intelligent way to develop my application avoiding being repetitive (`AsyncTask` has a lot of boilerplate code). The way I did was by creating 20+ subclasses of `AsyncTask`, which clearly is not DRY (do not repeat yourself).

In iOS we have lambda expressions so callbacks done in web requests are very easy and succinct.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is -- but on your last point, yes you should avoid parsing on the UI thread if it all possible, especially if you are going to spinning up a thread for the HTTP call it would make sense to do the parsing on this thread.

Comment: You don't have to write that full code each time. AsyncTask is a class that can be extended or used in other ways.

Comment: @JosephEarl I want to know a simpler way avoid those repetitive code that AsyncTask requires. I create a class for each subclassed type of AsyncTask, but in my project I have 20+ classes of AsyncTask. Is it normal?

Comment: @zapl I rephrased my question. Please take a look again. I appreciate

Comment: If your usecase are HTTP calls I'd suggest you use a library that did the complicated class / API design to reduce duplication for you too. You can write your own wrappers around asynctask, (E.g. `CursorLoader` is based on `AsyncTask` and has a completely different way you use it) but it is a lot of work. You could try create an abstract class with just `Object1` as generic parameter and get less boilerplate that way. Or pass in a strategy pattern like object that handles those things in a generic way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create classes that contain most of your boilerplate code. E.g.

```
public class SpecialAsyncTask<T> extends AsyncTask<String, Void, T> {

    public interface ResultProvider<T> {
        T generateResultInBackground(String... params);
    }

    public interface ResultConsumer<T> {
        void handleResultInForeground(T result);
    }

    private final ResultProvider<T> mProvider;
    private final ResultConsumer<T> mConsumer;
    private SpecialAsyncTask(ResultProvider<T> provider, ResultConsumer<T> consumer) {
        mProvider = provider;
        mConsumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    protected T doInBackground(String... params) {
        return mProvider.generateResultInBackground(params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(T result) {
        mConsumer.handleResultInForeground(result);
    }

    public static <T> void execute(ResultProvider<T> provider, ResultConsumer<T> consumer, String... params) {
        new SpecialAsyncTask<T>(provider, consumer).execute(params);
    }
}
```

is an example how you could keep `Object1` as a generic parameter while being able to specify an object that only needs to implement an interface to handle code that would otherwise have to be inside a new `AsyncTask` instance.

With a schema like that you could for example define some common code as static content:

```
class Providers {
    public static final ResultProvider<String> HTTP_GETTER = new ResultProvider<String>() {

        @Override
        public String generateResultInBackground(String... params) {
            return MagicHttpLibrary.getContentAsString(params[0]);
        }

    };
}
```

And you can just use `Providers.HTTP_GETTER` as parameter instead of implementing `doInBackground`. Or create a new class hierarchy of that implement one of those interfaces with different methods to access them (like factories for example)

Use of above example would look for example like below

```
class User extends Activity implements ResultConsumer<String> {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SpecialAsyncTask.execute(Providers.HTTP_GETTER, this , "http://google.com");
        SpecialAsyncTask.execute(Providers.HTTP_GETTER, this , "http://yahoo.com");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResultInForeground(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and there is more or less no repeated code besides the different method calls. It depends on how you want to use a class and what actually changes in the code to know how to design something like that. Identify the parts that need to be parametrized and move code that repeats into a re-used place (inheritance / composition).

Answer (score 0):

Google's [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master) HTTP request library does the request and parsing both in the same worker thread. So, that's a pretty good example to code by.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see the need to use Google's Volley. I'm just asking an optimized and DRY way of creating different web requests with different callbacks without creating a lot of subclasses of `AsyncTask`s